# How to make Height and Width of ScrollView Still The same Before ZoomIn on UIImage?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Hello All iOS developer I'm new at iOS development. at the moment I work In the case I want to Zoom Picture, I use UIImageView in UIScrollView. Everything is Ok on ScrollView Height and Width but when I try to ZoomIn and ZoomOut to make to current Size of Image the UIScrollView has Increase the Height and Width. and I try to find out the solution but it's work.I need some help.thank you in advance.
[This's The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5ApV.jpg)

```
 Here is my code

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initializeLanguages()
    checkForm()
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.bounces = false
    scrollView.delegate = self
    lblRetake.textColor = TrueColor.trueColorbrand()
    updateZoom()
    scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    scrollView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    setShadowView(view: viewContainer)
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addViewGesture()
    displayImage()
}
//MARK: ZoomOut/ZoomIn Image
func updateZoom() {
    let fwidth = self.imageView.image?.size.width ?? 0
    let fheight = self.imageView.image?.size.height ?? 0
    var minZoom = min(fwidth, fheight);
    if (minZoom > 1) {
        minZoom = 1;
    }

    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minZoom;
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = minZoom;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
}
```

Comment: Show the code moji.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini ok